# Help Understanding a Lemma: if $\exists X$ such that $X=A \backslash g(B \backslash f(X))$ then there exists a bijection from $A$ to $B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

I had a Lemma in one of my algebraic structure class that I was never really able to grasp the use of.
We used it to prove *Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein*'s theorem, but I never used it after that, nor remember the teacher using it.
I'd love to have some help. If anyone could provide an example (intuitive or use), I'd be very grateful.

*The Lemma:*

Let $f:A\rightarrow B$ and $g:B\rightarrow A$ two injections. If there exists a subset $X\subseteq A$ such that $X=A \backslash g(B \backslash f(X))$, then there exists a bijection $A\rightarrow B$.

Thank you.

Comment: I do not quite understand your question. A lemma is by  definition a claim whose use primarily consists in structuring a proof. The lemma you mention has such a use in the context of the standard proof of Schröder-Bernstein. So where is the problem?

Comment: Well...The claim is strong. It could be of some use for prooving isomorphisms for example... no? My question is: is there any other use of this lemma other then prooving CSB's theorem?

Comment: OK, now I see what your question is.

Comment: In case it helps to get better understanding of the lemma here is
[a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nfwry.png) which I use when teaching the topic. And [a similar picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KxvX.png) is used on [French Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me_de_Cantor-Bernstein) ([current revision](https://fr.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me_de_Cantor-Bernstein&oldid=179021551)).

Comment: Thanks! I'll see if it helps